# Manual of glib and multithreading

Tags: gtk, glib

Is anywhere book or good manual, but better book about GTK+/glib, and multithreading in C/GTK+? I need to run a function in another thread than main window, and make it cancellable.

Answer (score 2):

[GCancellable](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/GCancellable.html) is part of the GIO I/O library. It provides a thread-safe way to simply send a "cancel yourself" message, and should be easy to implement in a thread of your own.

Simply create an instance of GCancellable using `g_cancelablle_new()`, and then either poll it periodically (using `g_cancellable_is_cancelled()`) in your thread, or use the signal support.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended. glib uses an event loop, so do your processing in slices via `g_timeout_*()` or `g_idle_*()`, and just stop processing when you want to cancel it.